# php: how to shorten many $_POST[];

Tags: php

I'm working on a page with many insert fields. 
how can i shorten the following code?

```
$title_1 = $_POST['title_1'];
$content_1 = $_POST['content_1'];
$link_1 = $_POST['link_1'];
$img_link_1 = $_POST['img_link_1'];

$title_2 = $_POST['title_2'];
$content_2 = $_POST['content_2'];
$link_2 = $_POST['link_2'];
$img_link_2 = $_POST['img_link_2'];

$title_3 = $_POST['title_3'];
$content_3 = $_POST['content_3'];
$link_3 = $_POST['link_3'];
$img_link_3 = $_POST['img_link_3'];
```

Comment: `if ($_POST['title_1'] ==...) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the $_POST array like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
}
```

This will make your post variable like `$_POST['title_1']` into `$title_1`

Remember your post names will have to be the exact names you want your variables to be referenced by.

Comment: Brilliant. I wasn't aware of the ${$variable} interpolation, but I always wondered if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
$howmany = 3; // How many sets of fields are submitted.

for($i=0;$i<$howmany;$i++){
  $field[$i]['title'] = $_POST['title_'.$i];
  $field[$i]['content'] = $_POST['content_'.$i];
  $field[$i]['link'] = $_POST['link_'.$i];
  $field[$i]['img_link'] = $_POST['img_link_'.$i];
}
```

Then you can access data in `$field[1]['title']` form.

Answer (score 0):

I redid this answer after you edited your post. Use variable variables.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    if (preg_match('/^(([a-z]+_)+\d)$/', $key, $match)
    {
        $$match[0] = $val;
    }
}
```

Use `[a-z0-9]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]` as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract (http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php): `extract($_POST)`

But you should be careful -- what if the client POSTs user_id, or something? At the least, you should specify that $_POST values won't overwrite already-defined variables: `extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$key_prefixes = array (
    'title',
    'content',
    'link',
    'img_link'
);

$i = 1;
while (true) {
    $post_values_missing = 0;
    foreach ($key_prefixes as $key_prefix) {
        $key = $key_prefix . '_' . $i;
        if (!isset($_POST[$key])) {
            $post_values_missing += 1;
            continue;
        };
        $val = $_POST[$key];
        // do something with $val
    }

    // did you get any values through this iteration?
    $post_values_exist_bool = (count($key_prefixes) !== $post_values_missing);

    // if not, you must've gotten them all
    if (false === $post_values_exist_bool) {  
        break;
    }

    $i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this would be to use PHP's POST data processing capabilities to do the work for you.

Consider using your HTML form names as follows:

```
<form action="{url}" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="data[0][title]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[0][content]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[0][link]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[0][image_link]" />

    <input type="text" name="data[1][title]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[1][content]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[1][link]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[1][image_link]" />

    ...

</form>
```

In PHP extract the data as follows:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

This shortens your PHP code to just one line. This statement will directly give you an array in PHP of the `data` form input. A `var_dump` will look as follows:

```
array (
    0 => array('title'=>'...','content'=>'...','link'=>'...','image_link'=>'...'),
    1 => array('title'=>'...','content'=>'...','link'=>'...','image_link'=>'...'),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Pretty impressive. I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your name, just make it array;

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" />
<input type="text" name="content[]" />
<input type="text" name="link[]" />
<input type="text" name="image_link[]" />

<input type="text" name="title[]" />
<input type="text" name="content[]" />
<input type="text" name="link[]" />
<input type="text" name="image_link[]" />

<input type="text" name="title[]" />
<input type="text" name="content[]" />
<input type="text" name="link[]" />
<input type="text" name="image_link[]" />
```

PHP:

```
extract($_POST);
$count=count($title);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {

//You can perform your any function on this loop, to get title use $title[$i]
}
```